# Дужки і тире при вставних реченнях

Tags: пунктуація, синтаксис

Прийшлося нещодавно робити повний синтаксичний розбір речення, яке ускладнене вставним реченням:

> Вишневий сад, — він тільки-но зацвів, — данину першу виплативши
>   бджолам, дрімав і спав (М. Рильський).

Виникли сумніви у правильності постановки тире. Чому не дужки?

Прочитала відповідну статтю в [«Практикумі з правопису і граматики української мови» І.П. Ющука](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf)  (Розділові знаки п.122. Інші розділові знаки). Він пише, що постановка тире і дужок пов’язані з певною інтонацією: підвищення (тире), подовження, пониження (дужки).

На іншому [сайті](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=1385)  прочитала більш детальну інформацію про вставні речення:

> Вставні слова, словосполучення й речення виражають особисте ставлення мовця до свого висловлювання й не несуть нової інформації, лише певним чином оцінюють, уточнюють основне повідомлення. Вставні слова, словосполучення й речення не є членами речення.
> Вставлені слова, словосполучення й речення вносять додаткову інформацію в речення, не будучи граматично пов'язані з ним (отже, як і вставні конструкції, вони не є членами речення).

Наводиться приклад постановки дужок, який знову мені показався сумнівним. Чому не тире?

> Там батько, плачучи з дітьми (а ми малі були і голі), не витерпів
>   лихої долі, умер на панщині! (Т. Шевченко).

Допоможіть, любі друзі, розібратися в умовах постановки знаків.